# Where does the Add method come from in DbContext class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been checking the DbContext class. It does not have an Add method. However, many examples use the Add method. I understand that it is a derived class of ObjectContext. There is an AddObject method. So are the Add and AddObject methods the same?

Comment: Is this a basic "How does inheritance work because I never learned object oriented programming?" question?

Comment: Can you show where you saw examples of Add being used?

Comment: @TomTom I don't think so. [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx), nor any of it's parents, have a `Add(` method.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain This is the website I was looking at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679587%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method you're talking about is method on [`DbSet<TEntity>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), and what you really see is something like that:

```
using(var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    ctx.Users.Add(newUser);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

It adds new item into given table, represented as `DbSet<TEntity>`. I've used `Users` as property name, but it will be different, depending on your context (most likely there will be more than one `DbSet<TEntity>` within your context).

Comment: Yep, with [the link he posted](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx) that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thanks for the reply. I appoligize in advance- I am a newbie to EF. How are the tables automatically connected to DbSet?

Comment: The name of entity is connected to table name, and properties to columns (unless you change that using fluent API or attributes).